# Does the java version make any difference when building a Flutter app?

Tags: java, flutter, build

I am wandering if building a Flutter app with different java versions make any difference. Could the version influence if the app crashes or not in an old device, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, It won't effect anything. However, if you're using some plugin/package that require specific java version, it might cause a problem. If your app crashes, read the log and see if it is caused by a package/plugin and if so, that particular package might need a specific version.